# How do I save multiple startup projects as a separate start type in a visual studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, app-startup

In visual studio there is a way to choose multiple projects for a startup via "Multiple startup projects" in a solution settings. I can even choose an order in which they are going to start with arrows, which is very helpful if order matters.
However from time to time I need to start a separate project and then get back to the same set of projects. It never saves it. Is there a way to save my set of projects and their order and name it with something custom so that I don't have to setup all this every time I restart vs or switch between projects?
I'm using Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022 Community.